# gnuplot display y2 values on x2

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have the following graph:

- first data set display searches.
- second data set display clicks.

`y1` shows searches scale, `y2` shows click scale.
on the `x1` I have time values displayed.

I wish to display clicks values (each hour) on `x2` (the upper axis).
When I add the command `set x2tics` it displays the searches data and not the clicks like I wished.

How do I change it so it will display the clicks unit?

Gnuplot script:

```
set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Times"
set y2range [0:55000]
set y2tics 0, 1000
set ytics nomirror
set datafile separator "|"
set title "History of searches"
set xdata time          # The x axis data is time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"        # The dates in the file look like 10-Jun-04
set format x "%d/%m\n%H:%M"
set grid
set terminal png size 1024,768        # gnuplot recommends setting terminal before output
set output "outputFILE.png"  # The output filename; to be set after setting
                     # terminal
load "labelsFILE"

plot 'goodFILE' using 1:3 lt 2 with lines t 'Success'  , 'clicksFILE' using 1:2 lt 5 with lines t 'Clicks right Y' axis x1y2


replot
```

Graph:

[graph http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/1269/wu0b.png](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/1269/wu0b.png)

Comment: I don't fully understand whats the problem. I would say use `x2y2`, instead of `x1y2`. But why do you want to plot the clicks against the `x2`-axis? Do you have a different timescale for them, or what?

Comment: Hi, i wish to leave the date/time data on x1 and add to x2 tics for # of clicks per hour. i don't have a different timescale for the clicks.
if i can add another tic data on the x1 it can be good also, just without hiding the date/time data.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have an idea of what you really want. Do you maybe want to place a label with the number of clicks every hour, like it could be done with the `labels` plot style?

Comment: I agree with Christoph. What additional information do you have for the 2nd `x`-axis? The way I understand your data is: you have `x1=time`, `y1=searches`; `x2=time`, `y2=clicks` - however, in your case `x1=x2`.

Comment: I agree that time is on x1,x2 but i wish to have clicks per hour sum on x1 or x2. maybe it's possible to put labels on the graph itself?
for example, if between 20:00 and 21:00 i had 43K clicks i wish to have the exact number per hour labeled on the 21:00 point in x2.
is that possible?
if i add "set x2tics" at the begining of the script it does add the data for searches (per half an hour), can't that be changed to clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so to get started, here is how you can set a label with the number of clicks as follows (using you data file names):

```
plot 'goodFILE' using 1:3 lt 2 with lines t 'Success',\
     'clicksFILE' using 1:2 lt 5 with lines t 'Clicks right Y' axis x1y2,\
     '' using 1:2:(sprintf("%dk", int($2/1000.0))) with labels axis x1y2 offset 0,1 t ''
```

Just add this as plotting command, and it should work just fine.

To illustrate, how the labels might look like, here is an example with some dummy data:

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'blubb.png'

set xlabel "Time"
set ylabel "Times"
set y2label "Clicks per hour"
set y2range [0:10000]
set yrange [0:1]
set ytics nomirror
set y2tics
set key left

set samples 11
set xrange[0:10000]
plot '+' using 1:1:(sprintf("%dk", int($1/1000.0))) every ::1::9 with labels axis x1y2 offset 0,1 t '',\
     '' using 1:1 with linespoints axis x1y2 pt 7 t 'Clicks per hour'
```

Which gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I've tried adding the suggested plot command and i get the following error:
plot 'good.1557' using 1:3 lt 2 with lines t 'Success',     'clicks.1557' using 1:2 lt 5 with lines t 'Clicks right Y' axis x1y2,     '' using 1:2:(sprintf("%dk", int($2/1000.0))) with labels axis x1y2 offset 0,1 t ''
                                                                                                                                                                
"plot.1557", line 22: invalid expression
the error is pointing at the "%dk" parameter inside the sprintf function.

Comment: i've tried changing it buit no luck.
what can cause this?
what gnuplot version do you use?
thanks!

Comment: To test this, I used version 4.6, but `sprintf` should be available since very early gnuplot versions. Can you compile my other example script without problems? Based on your comment, without proper formatting, it is rather difficult to unterstand the error message.

Comment: The `labels` plotting style is available since version 4.2. Use only `using 1:2:2` to see, if `sprintf` is really the problem.

Comment: the error is:  
    "line 22: invalid expression"  
and it's pointing at the "%dk" parameter inside the sprintf function.

Comment: so it's probably the reason. i'm using version 4.0

Comment: using `1:2:2` is not working, fails on the `x1y2`, it's expecting an other command.
your example also fails on the same part, i'll upgrade gnuplot and let you know.

Comment: +1 for digesting the question, providing a detailed answer (& graph), and a copy/paste example. works for me.

Comment: I've tested it with `4.2.6` and it works! thank you! i've tested it on development server and it did throw the following message: `Could not find/open font when opening font "arial", using internal non-scalable font`. any idea?

Comment: The font is not found, this depends on your OS and `libgd` settings. I don't know how to fix that. BTW: Why don't you use the current gnuplot version 4.6.3? The terminal `pngcairo`, or even `pdfcairo` gives better images than `png`.

Comment: That version was already installed on a running server. they don't give away root in my company and the IT resources is very low. i'm glad i had this version to test it. i'll install it when i move to a better production server.